# Fabric Beta: Channel conflict between orgs?

Tags: android, fabric-beta

I am trying to distribute two Android apps with the same package name through two different orgs in Fabric Beta (I realize this is an odd thing to do, but they're different versions of the same app and for reasons I need to see if I can keep them in separate channels).

I can upload the apks to both orgs fine (and they end up in different channels--one for each org). The problem is that when I try to add both of the channels to a single device, only the first channel added is available. It seems like when I try to add the second channel the Fabric Android Beta app just thinks that the second channel has already been added, so it just loads up that already added channel, and the second channel is never added.

Is this intended or expected behavior?

Is there any way to have two channels (from different orgs) on the same device that distrubute apks with the same package?

I realize that I could change the package name, but I would like to avoid that if possible so that we can still test upgrade scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Two different apps can't have the same package name. Even on play store, the package name is the unique identifier. You can use 2 different packages for the same code base using build flavors.

Ideally, the package name is denoted as

com.company.product

So it's preferable to create 2 different apps

Comment: Thanks! It's actually different versions of the same app that I need to distribute to different groups. I also want to try to keep the package name the same so that we can test upgrade scenarios. I realize that this is an odd scenario. I'm just confused as to why the Fabric Beta app ignores a second channel from a different org if it happens to already have a channel with a matching package name.

Comment: Its because Fabric follows exactly the same principle as play store. It considers package name as unique identifier and will not allow anyone else (from same org or diff org) to use same package name for a different app.